# iPhone 4S won't mount on my laptop running Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: acer, aspire-one

My laptop is an Acer Aspire D257. I have tried a couple commands but I can't get my iPhone 4S to mount, it charges and shows up but just wont mount. Is there any way to get music into my iPhone at all with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ifuse` to mount your iphone in ubuntu.

Install it bu typing following command in terminal :`sudo apt-get install ifuse`

It is a FUSE filesystem driver which uses libiphone to connect to iPhone
and iPod Touch devices without needing to "jailbreak" them.